# USB devices not being detected in VirtualBox

Tags: 14.04, networking, usb, virtualbox

My USB is not being detected in the guest OS in VirtualBox.

Host OS: `Ubuntu 14.04`
Guest OS: `Windows 10`
VirtualBox version: `5.0.26 r108824`

USB is connected and detected in the host OS:

```
karl@karl:/$ sudo lsusb
...more
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 17cc:1100 Native Instruments
...more
```

My user has been added to the `vboxusers` group:

```
karl@karl:/$ groups
karl adm dialout cdrom sudo audio dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare vboxusers docker bumblebee realtime
```

Guest Additions has been installed. The VirtualBox Guest Additions icon is in the guest OS's system tray.

I have enabled USB in the VirtualBox settings; `Enable USB Controller` is ticked. I've chosen the `USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller` controller.

I've restarted my host OS.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a post on some random forum saying that 14.04 had issues with this. I reinstalled VirtualBox with the latest version and now it works.

Comment: Can you **[edit]** this to include a link to the post?